# highcharts add yAxis label based on negative/positive value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart that shows the trade balance between the US and other countries over time.

I need the ability to show on the right side of the chart that positive numbers are imports (positive trade balance) and that negative numbers are exports (negative trade balance).

A badly written start can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0s17qt56/)

I'm attempting to add the import/export labels with the following (ugly) code:

```
 yAxis: [{

        title: {
            text: 'Millions of Dollars'
        }
    },{
        opposite: true,
        title : {
          rotation: 0,
          text: 'Imports',
          x: 17,
          y: -48
      }
    },{
      opposite: true,
        title : {
          rotation: 0,
          text: 'Exports',
          x: -40,
          y : 5
      }
    }]
```

I'm looking to create something like a category on the yAxis for positive and negative values to label positive values as imports and negative values as exports.

Would like to keep in highcharts so all the nice options that come with highcharts (download, etc) shows this secondary yAxis labels as well.

Is there something simple I'm missing to make this work?

Thanks!!

Comment: I dont understand, when I see your chart it has imports/exports on the side, can you be more clear?

Comment: If the question is whether Highcharts has this capability built-in, the answer is (a) I don't know, (b) I don't think so, (c) what you're doing is probably the way to do it.

Comment: @JordanHendrix It does show but it feels too ugly and that my `x` and `y` values will have to be manually changed based on chart size.  Would also like the tick mark behavior that you get when showing categories.

Comment: The goal is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/o9fk6zbk/ ? Could you post the mockup of requested chart?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't your own solution, here's my own dirty hacky solution which is probably worse, but you at least don't need to specify positions for the axes (sort of).

The idea is to add an extra category with no name, add another series with 2 points with an x value of that category and a name being "import" and "export".

You could eventually derive the values of these 2 "hidden" points based on the data you have so they can adjust automatically. It's dirty but it works.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Widget trade balance'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec',
                ""
            ],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: [{

            title: {
                text: 'Millions of Dollars'
            }
        }],

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [ 
                {            
                    type: "scatter",                    
                color: "transparent",
                data: [ { x:12, y:20,name:"Imports" }, { x:12, y:-20,name:"Exports" } ],
                showInLegend: false,
                dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                    formatter: function () { return this.point.name; },                    
                    y: 10
                }
            },
        {
            name: 'Canada',
            data: [-83.6, -78.8, -98.5, -93.4, -66.0, -44.5, -105.0, -104.3, -91.2, -83.5, -106.6, -92.3]

        }, {
            name: 'Mexico',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'England',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }]
    });
});
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r2etx98t/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following to manually position the text

See working http://jsfiddle.net/0s17qt56/4/

excerpt below

```
labels: {
      items : [{
         html : 'Imports',
         style : {
           left: '710px',
           top : '130px'
         }
       },{
         html : 'Exports',
         style : {
           left: '710px',
           top : '70px'
         }
       }]
    },
```